# JPA Criteria : Using order-by clause by truncating date

Tags: date, jpa, sql-order-by, criteria-api

How to create an "**order by**" clause in JPA criteria API, to sort date field by avoiding the time part of the date.

Something equivalent to :-  `SELECT EMP_NAME,DOJ FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY trunc(DOJ)`.

Comment: Since you're only sorting by this column, sorting by date and time will lead to an acceptable result: the rows will be sorted by date.

Comment: @siebz0r :- As described in the question, The DOJ field will contain date + time, when it is entered in the DB . But in some scenarios, need to avoid the time part and show the details of the emplouee based on date only (say displaying on sceen).

Comment: @JB Nizet :- Suppose I want to sort on one more column (say order by DOJ, name).   In this case it can cause problem.

Comment: How you display your data has nothing to do with how you fetch it. Just fetch the data using date+time and when you display the date, strip the time off. In short, go with @JBNizet 's answer.

Comment: Suppose I want to sort the employee details based on DOJ(desc) and NAME (asc). There are two emps. (1st emp)- DOJ=13-Jun-12 10:00:00, name=ABC,  (2nd emp)- DOJ=13-Jun-12 11:00:00, name=PQR. Here if we consider date+time, 2nd emp will come first since hour 11>10. But if we avoid the time part in the date field, 1st emp will come first and then the 2nd emp.(This is what I need).  Hope the example explains the issue i faced.

Answer (score 0):

The JPA 2.0 spec does not define any date extraction functions.  So you need to either use native SQL, or syntax specific to your JPA provider.

If you are using EclipseLink 2.4 you can use EXTRACT,

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions

In previous EclipseLink versions you can use FUNC to call a database specific function in JPQL.

The JPA 2.1 draft defines a FUNCTION operator for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CriteriaBuilder#function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...%29) to do your date extraction. But be careful, this method rely on RDBMS specific functions: this is **NOT** portable.

See an example that we use with postgresql

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = cq.from(Employee.class);
String postgresTimeUnit = "day";
Expression<Calendar> dateTruncExpr = cb.function("date_trunc", Calendar.class, cb.literal(postgresTimeUnit), employee.get(Employee_.date)).as(Calendar.class);

cq.select(
    employee
).where(
    // where stuff
).orderBy(
    cb.asc(dateTruncExpr)
);
```

This example uses the postgresql function **date_trunc** and its specific dsl to describe date fields ('day' here indicates we want to extract the day of our date field)

The sql query is generated as follow:

```
select employee0_.id as col_0_0_, employee0_.name as col_0_1_, employee0_.date as col_0_2_ from employee employee0_ order by date_trunc(?, employee0_.date) asc
```